# Как подключить по SSH за NAT

Tags: linux, ssh, ethernet

Есть устройство за NAT и динамическим IP но которое может постоянно поддерживать соединения с сервером и вопрос имея доступ к серверу как можно подключиться к этому устройству?

Comment: http://blog.barak.in/2008/09/ssh.html

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: Кроме мониторинга по крону, есть и готовая обёртка для запуска и мониторинга работоспособности сессии — autossh

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev что за готовая обертка? Не autossh?

Comment: @users да, я так и написал — «готовая обёртка — autossh»

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev а, да, не заметил autossh